# Bash: Move all directories where the directory path does not contain a particular string

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a directory with two subdirectories A and G. Directory A contains two subdirectories (B and C). Directory B also contains two subdirectories (D and E). Finally, directory D contains directory F.

```
.
├── A
│   ├── B
│   │   ├── D
│   │   │   └── F
│   │   └── E
│   └── C
└── G
```

Now, I want to move all directories where their path does not contain B/D to directory G. Assuming I'm in the top directory where A and G exist, I'm trying this command:

```
    $shopt -s extglob
    $mv !(*B/D*) ./G
```

But I'm getting this error: `mv: rename !(*B/D*) to ./G/*: No such file or directory` . Any ideas? I'm also open to other ways of solving the problem.

Comment: I presume you have a whole lot more directories than that in reality?  Otherwise the simple answer is just mv ./A/B/E ./A/B.C ./G

Comment: Of course! And name of directories are not static. They could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Using `find`:

```
find A/ -depth -type d -not \( -name *A* -o -name *B* -o -name *D* \) -exec mv -t G/ {} +
```

**Example:**

```
$ tree
.
├── A
│   ├── B
│   │   ├── D
│   │   │   └── F
│   │   └── E
│   └── C
└── G

$ find A/ -depth -type d -not \( -name *A* -o -name *B* -o -name *D* \) -exec mv -t G/ {} +

$ tree
.
├── A
│   └── B
│       └── D
└── G
    ├── C
    ├── E
    └── F
```

---

If your `mv` does not have `-t` option:

```
find A/ -depth -type d -not \( -name *A* -o -name *B* -o -name *D* \) -exec mv {} G/ \;
```

Comment: The problem with the answer is that it moves directory F which should not because ABDF contains BD. It only keeps ABD but it should be ABDF.

Comment: Another problem is that it does not keep the directory structure. Directory E is actually BE relative to A. So, when moved to G, it should be GBE.

Comment: Using `-wholename` should let the simpler `*B/D*` match from the first attempt work... I think. Using `-execdir` should also make fixing the structure issue fairly doable (by getting the current directory prefix and using `mkdir -p` on it in the new path).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct answer:

```
find A/ -depth -type d -not \( -wholename "*B" \) -not \( -wholename "*B/D*" \) -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p G/`dirname "{}"`; mv "{}" G/`dirname "{}"`' \;
```